# PHP & MYSQL Return blank page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on the PHP and MYSQL for a project and I encountered a weird problem here where I click on the submit button at the form, it will run these codes. However the weird problem is the the page return blank instead of going back to the page with the form. I had searched for few hours for the error but couldn't find it.

Please point out my mistake. Thank you for the help.

```
<?php
include '../database.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

    if (isset($_POST['stuid_0'])){

        $student = $_POST['stuid_0'];


        //query moderator details
        $query = mysql_query(" SELECT ModeratorID FROM Student WHERE StuID ='$student' ") or die(mysql_error());
        $info = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query);
        $dbmoderator = $info['ModeratorID'];

            //check for changes of status in supervisor
            $query2 = mysql_query(" SELECT SupervisorID FROM Student WHERE StuID ='$student' ") or die(mysql_error());
            $value = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query2);
            $dbsupervisor = $value['SupervisorID'];
            $query3 = mysql_query(" SELECT LectStatus FROM Lecturer WHERE LectID ='$dbsupervisor' ") or die(mysql_error());
            $value2 = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query3);
            $dbsupervisorstatus = $value2['LectStatus'];

            //if no changes in supervisor
            if ($dbsupervisorstatus=='2'){ 
                echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.alert('Moderator can't be promoted')
                window.location.href='../committee/committee_supervisor2.php'
                </SCRIPT>"); 

            }
            else{
             //newly assigned a supervisor if previous supervisor status is not active
            $query4 = "UPDATE Student SET SupervisorID='$dbmoderator', SupervisorStatus='1', ModeratorID=NULL WHERE StuID='$student'";
            mysql_query($query4);

            echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.alert('Successfully updated')
                window.location.href='../committee/committee_supervisor2.php'
                </SCRIPT>"); 
            }
    }
    else
        echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('You must choose a moderator to be promoted')
        window.location.href='../committee/committee_supervisor2.php'
        </SCRIPT>");
}
?>
```

UPDATE: 
I think the problem happen when the system run at this point

```
if ($dbsupervisorstatus=='2'){
```

As i put an echo "Test"; before this line and it still work.

UPDATE 2:

I found that the code can be run when I put

```
if ($dbsupervisorstatus=='2'){ 
                echo "Moderator can't be promoted"; 

            }
```

as well as

```
  if($dbsupervisorstatus == 2){
  header("location:commitee_supervisor2.php");
   }
```

However I don't see the reason why my original code

```
if ($dbsupervisorstatus=='2'){ 
                echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.alert('Moderator can't be promoted')
                window.location.href='../committee/committee_supervisor2.php'
                </SCRIPT>"); 

            }
```

Not working.. A little help pls.. :)

**FINAL UPDATE**

Guys, I know why.

It's because the

```
window.alert('Moderator can't be promoted')
```

have 3 apostrophe in it.

I simply remove the word "can't" and its working already.

Thank you guys for the help :)

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? (`error_reporting(E_ALL)`)

Comment: why don't you simply do a redirect to your commitee_supervisor2 page instead of doing it through javascript?

Comment: castis, can you please teach me how to turn the error reporting on? where should i put it? ps. im a newbie in php.. tq for the response.

Comment: Do redirection in server side, not on client side. Not the solution to your problem but just a pointer.

Comment: coder101, oh.. that is because i would like to alert the user on what is happening..

Comment: itachi, thank you for your suggestion.. i'll put that in mind :)

Comment: @user2126678 put `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of that script. that should put out all errors that are being generated. Remember to remove it before your code goes into production.

Comment: i've posted a sample code for redirection on server as @itachi pointed out. Also, if u want to put an alert, i would suggest making an AJAX request, that way you'd be in a position to do much better than an alert.

Comment: have you tried checking your apache error logs? if its echoing a test before the line where you do a comparison, the log file must have pointed out a problem

Comment: coder101, thank you for the response. I would check on how to put alert after this. thank you so much:)

Comment: let me know, if you need any more help with this.

Comment: hi coder101, i'm still wondering why isnt the javascript working while i have them work before in previous modules..

Comment: hi coder101, i found the mistake i made, thanks for the help, your effort in helping is much appreciated :)

Comment: all's well that ends well. Actually i didn't go through your javascript inside your PHP as i've always found it a bit dirty(pardon me) way of doing it. Traditional redirect is better and the best is AJAX, i almost always use it. Give it a try once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing it through javascript, try using a much better approach in pure PHP. Something like:

```
  if($dbsupervisorstatus == 2){
  header("location:commitee_supervisor2.php");
   }
```

And if you must use JS, then make an AJAX request, then you can manipulate the behaviour through JS anyway you like.

Answer (score 1):

Using the JavaScript codes code still work but the starting point of your debugging is to echo ordinary texts at all the places where you echo JavaScript. That will help you know at what point you codes started failing. Example

```
//if no changes in supervisor
            if ($dbsupervisorstatus=='2'){ 
                echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.alert('Moderator can't be promoted')
                window.location.href='../committee/committee_supervisor2.php'
                </SCRIPT>"); 

            }
```

Replace with

```
//if no changes in supervisor
            if ($dbsupervisorstatus=='2'){ 
                echo "Moderator can't be promoted"; 

            }
```

Do this at all echo points then start replacing one after the other with your JavaScript codes again then you'll spot out where your code fails.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you put your HTML form? Is it in the same page or different page? From your code, looks like there's nothing being done, so I suggest you to check whether your submit button name is correct (submit). The HTML should be like this:

```
<form name="your_form">
    <!-- Your form here -->

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi there, I had confirm that it is working as the echo can be shown however if I used back the original code, its not working anymore.. I used that in other module and its working fine.. What do you think? Thank you for the response :)